# Ditto (clipboard manager) troubleshooting in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, clipboard, ditto

Is there a way to make [ditto](http://ditto-cp.sourceforge.net/) paste text instantly on enter click after selection on Windows 7?

My flow is :

1. Bring ditto by clicking <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+**<kbd>'</kbd>**
2. Select desired text.
3. Press `ENTER` key on keyboard.
4. Now I need to do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to paste it. I want that on the `ENTER` the text will be pasted.

My options in ditto were already set to “Paste Clip in active window after selection”:

[image]

Comment: We generally use the word “click” only for mouse buttons.  To “click on” something means to point to it with your mouse pointer and press a mouse button (or do an analogous action with another pointing device, such as touchpad, trackball, or touchscreen).  When you say “click ```ENTER```” and “enter click”, do you mean “press (Enter)” (type the “Enter” ***key***), or are you referring to some action with a pointing device?  … … …  Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same problem with Ditto with Visual Studio 2012. The problem was I run VS2012 with elevated rights eg. Administrator Mode. My Ditto did not. I had run my Ditto also in administrator mode. Then it worked.

Hope this helpes.

Answer (score 2):

Under Options/General, turn on **Paste clip in Active Window after double click**.

Now you can put the caret in the target textbox, bring up the Ditto window, double click the clip you want, and it will automatically paste into the textbox.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, it does not seem to help me. Please see my updated question.

Answer (score 1):

This functionality works fine for me, are you trying it perhaps in applications that don't accept <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>?

If that is the case - go to the help and look for "Custom Keystrokes" (should be file:///C:/Program%20Files/Ditto/Help/DittoCustomKeys.htm)

There it explains how you can "program" Ditto to send the appropriate paste signal to specific applications.

Example:
`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Ditto\PasteStrings\SecureCRT.exe=+{INS}` -> This will send <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ins</kbd> when running in `SecureCrt`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Did you mean CTRL+V in your first sentence?

Comment: Yes, Thank you for pointing it out. I updated the answer now.